# Change the look in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

I tried to change the look of team site, site settings > change the look

Once I click on Try it Out I received

> Sorry, something went wrong  The requested layout URL is invalid.

The URL in address bar is **_layouts/15/DesignPreview.aspx**

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Did you checked Site Contents ->Site Pages -> Home.aspx ? Is it working? did u checked with by creating another subsite and with out applying change the look?

Comment: without any parameter the DesignPreview.aspx will ran into this error. But why it doesn't get ....?layoutUrl=.... etc.? I've seen this effect only once and there was low memory of the client the reason. Could you check whether this effect is shown on another client or on your client with reduced application running?

Comment: are you configure https?!